# Pandas dataframe: how to create columns from values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
            day payment_method  actuals  
 0   2015-03-31      DCASH_T3M       32        
 1   2015-03-31   DCASH_T3M_3D       90        
 2   2015-03-31         PAYPAL       34        
 4   2015-04-01      DCASH_T3M       16       
 5   2015-04-01   DCASH_T3M_3D       54       
 6   2015-04-01         PAYPAL       33        
 7   2015-04-02      DCASH_T3M        7       
 8   2015-04-02   DCASH_T3M_3D       80       
 9   2015-04-02         PAYPAL       38
```

What i want to do is to perform time series analysis on them. It would be advantageous if I had a column for each payment method reporting the corresponding actuals and order total values and times series.

```
       day DCASH_T3M DCASH_T3M_3D PAYPAL
2015-03-31        32          90      34
2015-04-01        16          54      33
2015-04-02         7          80      38
```

datatime object would be a new column with distinct date for each roe. The values of the column payment_method would be the three new columns each of them containing the values in actuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
In [27]:
df.pivot(index='day', columns = 'payment_method', values = 'actuals')

Out[27]:
payment_method  DCASH_T3M  DCASH_T3M_3D  PAYPAL
day                                            
2015-03-31             32            90      34
2015-04-01             16            54      33
2015-04-02              7            80      38
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
data = data.pivot(index=`'day', columns='payment_method',values='actuals)`
```